# OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, sockets

I was testing out a client-side scheme here

server and client use same port 9009 to connect

somehow the following code gives me OSError as wrote in the titile:

```
import sys
import socket
import select

def chat_client():
    if(len(sys.argv) < 3) :
        print ('Usage : python chat_client.py hostname port')
        sys.exit()

    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)

    # connect to remote host
    try :
        s.connect((host, port))
    except :
        print ('Unable to connect')
        sys.exit()

    print ('Connected to remote host. You can start sending messages')
    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()

    while 1:
        socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

        # Get the list sockets which are readable
        ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(socket_list,[],[])
        # the timeout argument is omitted in above code,so chat_client blocks until a fd is ready
        for sock in ready_to_read:             
            if sock == s:
                # incoming message from remote server, s
                data = sock.recv(4096)   # sock.recv argument is buffsize, recommend 4096
                if not data :            # if not (data is not none), data is empty
                    print ('\nDisconnected from chat server')
                    sys.exit()
                else :                   # data has something
                    #print data
                    sys.stdout.write(data)   # write something to standard output buffer
                    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush() # write everything to terminal from buffer

            else :     # sock ! = s
                # user entered a message
                msg = sys.stdin.readline()    # readline pick up everything from stdin
                s.send(msg)
                sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush() 

if __name__ == "__main__":

  sys.exit(chat_client())
```

Any one can give me some tips on this ?  :)

Comment: i got this error when running flask from cmd within PyCharm. Switched to Windows CMD Window and the error is gone.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>         socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]
>
>         # Get the list sockets which are readable
>         ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(socket_list,[],[])
> ```

[Python »   Documentation » The Python Standard Library » 16. Optional Operating System Services » 16.1. `select` — Waiting for I/O completion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html):

> … Note that on Windows, it only works for sockets; on other operating
>   systems, it also works for other file types …

So, unlike on a sane OS, we cannot use `sys.stdin` here.