# WinError 10038 an operaton was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: windows, python-3.x, sockets

I'm trying to make chatting server in Python and I can't solve it. I'm running my code in CMD by using command python client.py localhost 9009.

this is the code that I am using:

```
#chat_client.py

import sys
import socket
import select

def chat_client():
if(len(sys.argv) < 3):
    print("Usage: python chat_client.py hostname port")
    sys.exit()

host = sys.argv[1]
port = int(sys.argv[2])

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(2)

# connect to remote host
try:
    s.connect((host, port))
except:
    print("Unable to connect")
    sys.exit()

print("Connected to remote host. You can start sending messages")
sys.stdout.write("[Me] "); sys.stdout.flush()

while 1:
    socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

    # Get the list sockets which are readable
    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

    for sock in read_sockets:            
        if sock == s:
            # incoming message from remote server, s
            data = sock.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                print("\nDisconnected from chat server")
                sys.exit()
            else:
                #print data
                sys.stdout.write(data)
                sys.stdout.write("[Me] "); sys.stdout.flush()     

        else:
            # user entered a message
            msg = sys.stdin.readline()
            s.send(msg)
            sys.stdout.write("[Me] "); sys.stdout.flush() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(chat_client())
```

And this is the error that I'm getting:
I don't have a clue how to fix it. Help would be appreciated! :)

```
[Me] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "client.py", line 54, in <module>
sys.exit(chat_client())
File "client.py", line 32, in chat_client
read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [],
[])
```

Comment: The problem is that on Windows, `select` only supports sockets.  You're trying to use it on `stdin`.  I don't know enough Python to advise on the best alternative, hopefully someone else can address that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369137/oserror-winerror-10038-an-operation-was-attempted-on-something-that-is-not-a